# Cannot open UIManagedDocument file seems to be corrupted after a few opens

Tags: ios, objective-c, uimanageddocument

I'm trying to open a `UIManagedDocument` after creating it. It seems to be unable to open the document after a few times of successfully opening the document. If I change the document name or delete/copy the app again, it works. The below method is called in the app delegate every time the application launches.

```
-(void) loadDataDocument {

    NSURL *documentURL= [[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory
                                                             inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"TestDataDocument1"];
    self.document = [[UIManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:documentURL];


    if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[documentURL path]]) {
    [self.document saveToURL:documentURL forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
        if (success) {
            [self documentIsReady];
        }else {
            NSLog(@"Tried to create new file. Cannot open document");
        }
    }];
    } else if (self.document.documentState == UIDocumentStateClosed) {
        [self.document openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
            if (success) {
               [self documentIsReady];
            }else {
               NSLog(@"Document was Closed. Cannot open document");
            }
        }];
    } else {
        [self documentIsReady];
    }
```

}

Comment: You need to show more code, this part of code looks clean to me. CS193P?

Comment: Yes...CS193P. Everyone seems to have knowledge using Persistent Stores but not UIManagedDocument

Comment: This is the only code I have. I call this method in application launch in the app delegate

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void) loadDataDocument {

    NSString * fileUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@abc.txt",[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject]];
    NSURL *documentURL= [NSURL URLWithString:fileUrl];

    UIManagedDocument *document = [[UIManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:documentURL];

    if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[documentURL path]]) {
        [document saveToURL:documentURL forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
            if (success) {
                NSManagedObjectContext * _context;
                _context = document.managedObjectContext;

            }
        }];
    } else if (document.documentState == UIDocumentStateClosed) {
             NSLog(@"document.documentState == UIDocumentStateClosed");
        NSString *fileDataStr = [[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:documentURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
        NSLog(@"%@",fileDataStr);
    } else {
        NSManagedObjectContext * _context;
        _context = document.managedObjectContext;

    }

}
```

**Note:**
    'UIManagedDocument can only read documents that are file packages'

Comment: Not sure what the purpose of this code is. Can you please give some context. I already check if the file exists. The problems comes when I open it.

Comment: oh i thought u only wanted to check wether the file exists or not. Can you brief a little what type of your document is ?

Comment: NSURL *documentURL= [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject]; it provides you the path till documents folder instead of a specific file you want to open...

Comment: example : /Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/6.1/Applications/44AFE37E-3C91-4F9F-9AB7-C5BB8D67A145/Documents/

Comment: kindly see the modified method

Comment: I appended the a file name but it still doesn't seem to work.